# Convert require to import es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to convert the following `require` to ES6 `import`.

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom'); 
var $ = require('jquery')(jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow);
```

I know that `var jsdom = require('jsdom');` is simple equivalent to `import jsdom from 'jsdom';` and `var $ = require('jquery');` is `import $ from 'jquery';`.

Now my question is where does `(jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow)` go to?

Do I write it as `import $ from 'jquery'(jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destruct it as follows;

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

const $ = jQuery(jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow);
```

since it is just using the return of imported `jquery` library inline.